# How to call kernel functions that are paged out in default IRQL? shouldn't memory manager bring them back to memory?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, wdk

I am directly calling some functions in other drivers (calling the DriverEntry of that driver)

The problem is that the page that contains that function seems to be paged out, because MmIsAddressValid returns false and also windbg says this when i try to go to that address :

```
Memory access error in 'u F72BA57F'
```

But the address is correct (the symbol get resolved and i can see that this in fact is the driverentry for that driver)

So my question is how can i bring the paged out code back to memory so i can call it? i don't mess with IRQL in my code and its running at default IRQL. i thought when i am running at default IRQL the memory manager will take care of the paged out stuff and bring it back to memory when i try to jump to it, but it seems to not do it since i get BSOD

by default IRQL i mean PASSIVE_LEVEL, based on my understanding the default in drivers is this if we don't mess with it, but correct me if I'm wrong.

I think using MmProbeAndLock might help, But I'm not sure how can i convert the address of EntryPoint of the driver to an MDL? because it seems to need an IRP to construct an MDL, but i am not sending an IRP?

Comment: If the other driver put its `DriverEntry` in the `INIT` text section with `#pragma alloc_text(INIT, DriverEntry)` then it will have been discarded from memory (along with any other functions in the `INIT` section) after the driver's `DriverEntry` function returned.

Comment: @IanAbbott So how can i bring it back to memory? is it possible? is this a paged out type of out-of-memory or ..?